# How to Increment Column value mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problem in increment and decresing a column in value please help me...

Error at,

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

```
UPDATE stock SET stock=stock+$quantity WHERE ID=1;
UPDATE stock SET stock=stock-$quantity WHERE ID=1;
```

Comment: are these queries in double `"` or single `'` quotes? ie. `"UPDATE ..."` or `'UPDATE ...'`? They should work, as long as the php vars are parsed.

Comment: stock is not a variable but the current stock on the db right?

Comment: yes $sql="UPDATE stock SET stock=stock+$quantity" thanks for your  reply

Comment: I suspect that we need to see the code

Comment: what is the type of your field: stock???

Comment: $sql="UPDATE 'stock' SET 'stock'='stock'-$quantity WHERE 'ID'=$id;";
if ($dbmysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
 echo true;
}

Comment: stock field type is int(11)

Answer (score 0):

try this one is work for me.

```
UPDATE `stock` SET `stock`=`stock`+$quantity where ID=1
```

also check you table field Type, incremental operator work in Integer or float type field only, in text or Varchar it will not work

Comment: $sql="UPDATE 'stock' SET 'stock'='stock'-$quantity WHERE ID=$id;";

Comment: can you check you field Type, incremental operator work in Integer or float type field only, in text or Varchar it will not work

Answer (score 0):

try static first

```
 UPDATE `stock` SET `stock`=`stock` + 200 where `ID` = 1
```